# add disclamier note in all splunk report at one shot

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

we want to add one disclaimer notes as below  on 50 reports of splunk.. can we do that in one shot?

Disclaimer:- In case you do not find any attachment OR Blank attachment this means no matching events or Blocked events were found during the report scheduled time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the CLI then you can edit the savedsearches.conf file(s) to add that text.  It should be faster than using the GUI.